# Software install error

Tags: windows-7, windows, installer

I've downloaded an installer for a piece of software which I've installed on many different computers already. When running the installer I get the following error:

> Failed to run setup.exe, working dir =
>   c:\users\dan\appdata\local\ckz_DTKK (check to see if this file is the
>   EXE)

I've checked that the installer isn't corrupt but the problem still occurs. Has anyone got any ideas as to how this error can be resolved?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information.  What software, what operating system, 32bit or 64bit, is the software 32 or 64, etc before we have enough information to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved after installing the pending Windows 7 updates.

Thanks for all the answers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its trying to extract a file "setup.exe" to the folder:

```
c:\users\dan\appdata\local\ckz_DTKK
```

If you run the installer again is the folder path the same? Are you running the program in the user context "dan"? If not there may be a permissions issue as the program is trying to extract to that folder.

(I've seen a similar problem in the past where an admin has installed a bit of software then another tries to repair or uninstall the software and they are unable to, as the base installer has been extracted to a location in the user's profile which the second user does not have access to.)

Comment: The user has admin rights and is called Dan.  The same path is used every time I try to install.  The OS has been upgraded to Windows 7 from Vista, maybe this could be part of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is the downloaded file the right size and have a non-default icon?

You could try redownloading it.

See if that folder exists in AppData and delete it before trying again.

Comment: The install is the correct size and I've downloaded it multiple times.  I've done an MD5 has to check that the installer is correct, which it is.  I'll have a go at deleting that folder though.